# jQuery not detected in Play Framework application

Tags: jquery, playframework

I'm not able to use jQuery/jQuery UI on my Play Framework application. I have included all the necessary stylesheets and js files. The page loads properly but Firebug error console shows `Jquery Undefined`. I cannot understand what's wrong here. Any ideas?

Comment: Impossible to answer without seeing some specifics

Answer (score 0):

You need to include your jQuery- and jQueryUI-files on your page. How does your `<script>`-tags look in your `<head>`-section of your page?

Answer (score 0):

JQuery is included by default in the main.html, which if you have extended the skeleton code that is created when you create a new play application, it is possible by adding your own script tags for jquery and jquery-ui, they are conflicting with the version already included?

Comment: Thanks for responding. I got it working. I guess it was some conflict happening while using play.

Answer (score 0):

Actually looks like a syntax error.

Are you using this syntax ?

```
$(function() {
    // Code
});
```

Plus if you try to include a file in play that does not exist if there is an error, play will display an error and not launch application. Makes me think, you are using jQuery the wrong way.

Checkout [jQuery documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page) and make sure, this is not a **jQuery related issue.**

Comment: Thanks for responding. I got it working. I guess it was some conflict happening while using play.

Comment: That is not possible. As Play is a server side framework there cannot be any conflict with Javascript libraries