# jQuery can't work with play framework

Tags: jquery, playframework

I searched same problem and found this.
[jQuery not detected in Play Framework application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7994422/jquery-not-detected-in-play-framework-application)
But I can't make sense which is the solution for the problem. So I made same kind of questions.

---

Develop environment
- Play 2.3.8
- sbt 0.13.8
- java 1.8
- scala 2.11
- Mac OSX 10.9
- jquery 1.11.3

I'm new on play framework. Just tried to use jquery in *.scala.html, it can't work. I checked that browser can get the js file with livehttp httpheader(304 status)
The code is follwoing.

```
<body>
  @content
  <script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/jquery.min.js")"></script>
  <script src="@routes.Assets.at("bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js")"></script>
</body>
```

I know this is really vague, but jquery can use so easily always. I don't know what to tell and say.

If I need more information, please tell me.

Thank you for your kindness.

Add what i want use jquery.

```
<div id="c1" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-8">
          <p class="lead">
            <i>sample item</i>
          </p>
          <p class="lead text-right">
            <i>sample, Inc.</i>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-8">
          <p class="lead">
            <i>sample2</i>
          </p>
          <p class="lead text-right">
            <i>AmericanInitiative, Inc.</i>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- carousel button -->
  <a class="carousel-control left carousel-black" href="#c1" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control right carousel-black" href="#c1" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure that you have the file named **jquery.min.js** under public/javascripts? What exactly is not working? You haven't used any jquery/javascript code in your HTML template

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  
- Yes, I have the file under public/javascripts.  
- I tried using carousel plugin with bootstrap

Comment: Maybe try some small example just to make sure everything is working: http://pastebin.com/xHuhza9S

Comment: it works! So, my html code on the above have some problems... Check it from now on.
Thank you for your help and sorry for make this kind of stuff question.

Comment: I'll post the detail after solve the problem.
Thanks again :D

Comment: I have the feeling that this has something to do with the location of the javascript code, the jquery reference and so on. You can try putting them in the `<head>` tag (although I know that putting them in the back of the `<body>` should give a better performance..)

Comment: Try putting the <script> that imports jQuery into the HTML head before all other imports.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you folks.
Finally, I solve the problem.
I'll leave the detail as following.

---

Conclusion :
- The path of "bootstrap.min.js" was wrong.
- There is no problem using jquery with play.
-- Should check the path of all file.

Detail :

I just tried using jquery with play via twitter bootstrap. Just like,

```
<div id="c1" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-8">
          <p class="lead">
            <i>sample item</i>
          </p>
          <p class="lead text-right">
            <i>sample, Inc.</i>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-8">
          <p class="lead">
            <i>sample2</i>
          </p>
          <p class="lead text-right">
            <i>AmericanInitiative, Inc.</i>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- carousel button -->
  <a class="carousel-control left carousel-black" href="#c1" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control right carousel-black" href="#c1" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

And thus, I need,

```
<head>
...
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="@routes.Assets.at("my_bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css")" >
...

</head>

<body>
  @content
  <script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/jquery.min.js")"></script>
  <script src="@routes.Assets.at("my_bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js")"></script>
</body>
```

But, the path of "bootstrap.min.js" was wrong. Both of "bootstrap.min.css" and "jquery.min.js" was correct, so it's hard to recognize path problem of "bootstrap.min.js" for me.

Thanks again.
See you again on another question ::)